# So i got the following error on the validator can anyone help me?

Tags: html, validation, metadata

Line 6, Column 66: Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

I just cant see what is wrong,

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Check this detail question and explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore this. The validator erroneously tries to map `http-equiv` metatags on known HTTP headers, but ignores the fact that an `X-` prefix indicates vendor specific extensions. This is a known issue of the validator and cannot be fixed on your end.

You could of course circumvent this by specifying it in the HTTP headers where it belongs, for example through Apache's mod_headers extensions. This requires code-level access to the site though.

Comment: The valdidator behavior is not erroneous. It checks according to HTML5 documents. Whether those documents have a wrong policy in this issue is a different question.